# What is the correct way in aurelia to bind on a custom element using repeat.for

Tags: javascript, aurelia

Using Aurelia I am struggling with binding and repeat.for :
suppose I have in my viewmodel with a property menuItems (an array of `MenuItem`) I would like to repeat the menuitems with a custom template  :

```js
export class App {
    menuItems : MenuItem[];
}
export class MenuItem{
   label:string;
}
```

In my app template I use use a custom element

```html
<require from="./menu-item"></require>
<ul>
  <menu-item repeat.for="item of menuItems"></menu-item>
</ul>
```

My custom template (menu-item.html):

```html
<template>
  <li>${label}</li>
</template>
```

What is the correct way the get the template bound or access the bound MenuItem?

I've tried the following: `${label}` and `${item.label}` but that does not work. I can see in the `bind(bindingContext)` callback that bindingContext has a property 'item' : `bindingContext.item` which is the MenuItem that is being bound.

I also tried to create bindable attribute on the MenuItem class:

```js
export class MenuItem{
   @bindable current any;
   label:string;
}
```

and the following repeater:

```
<menu-item repeat.for="item of menuItems" current.bind="item"></menu-item>
```

and a corresponding template

```html
<template>
  <li>${current.label}</li>
</template>
```

*note: see edit 1 below, for my comment on this point in the code.*

This approach also does not work.

Other explorations included not using a custom element (worked), using `<compose view-model='MenuItem', model.bind='item'/>`, does not work in this example either and would be to elaborate, I think.

Working solution, see also [Aurelia repeat.for binding on a custom element](https://gist.run/?id=0efbaea028450163d98e) 
:

repeat and bind on a custom attribute of the template and viewmodel class:

```html
<menu-item repeat.for="item of menuItems" current.bind="item" containerless></menu-item>
```

The viewmodel class:

```js
import {bindable, customElement} from 'aurelia-framework'

@customElement('menu-item')
export class MenuItem{
  label = "default label";
  @bindable current;

  constructor(label){
    this.label = label;
  }
  attached(){
    console.log("MenuItem = attached");
  }
}
```

## Edit 1:

I see in the output the html of templates repeated for as many there are MenuItems. But these items are not bound: the `<li>` is empty. I expected to see the labels.

## Edit 2:

in this post I typed "items in menuItems", that's not correct it should be "item of menuItems". But that was not the cause of my struggling, I had it mis-typed in this post only

## Edit 3:

@jeremy-danyow suggested that

- html should be well formed:  menu-item within ul is not correct (using `containerless` attribute helps by removing the menu-item element)
- custom elements should always have a closing tag 
  I have adapted the code.
  Also I made a plunker: [Aurelia repeat.for binding on a custom element](https://gist.run/?id=0efbaea028450163d98e)

That plunker works, provided a `@bindable` attribute;

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm trying to do something similar

Answer (score 4):

Browsers only allow `li` elements inside `ul` elements.  `<ul><menu-item></menu-item></ul>` is invalid markup in the same way that `<ul><div></div></ul>` is invalid markup.

Consider making a `<menu>` element whose template contains the `ul` and it's `li` elements instead.

One other thing- only a few standard elements are "self closing"- eg inputs, etc.  Custom elements must always have a closing tag.
Bad: `<menu-item />`
Good: `<menu-item></menu-item>`

You might be wondering "why can't aurelia figure this out for me?"

Valid question. Here's why: Aurelia does not implement a custom html parser.  It uses the DOM to parse standard HTML.  This is different than other frameworks folks might be accustomed to that implement custom parsers for non-standard markup syntaxes.

Comment: Your suggestion about well structured html is helpful and to the point. In my real world application I use the containerless attribute or the @containerless() decorator. Also the requirement of custom element needing a closing tag is good to know. I'll edit the question.
But the binding question remains open. Could you say anything about that?