# AureliaJS - replacing looped elements with a template (passing values?)

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I have found https://sean-hunter.io/2016/10/23/inter-component-communication-with-aurelia/ where it is explained how simple communication of values can be made between a parent and a child template.

Now, I'm trying to apply that to the contact manager tutorial:

- http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/contact-manager-tutorial/1

... also on https://github.com/aurelia/app-contacts/tree/master/src - in particular to the looped contact items, but I cannot get it to work.

I have made gists as an example, which can run on gist.run (note, gist.run seems to only work in Chrome, not in Firefox 50 yet - but you can replace `gist.run/?id=` with `gist.github.com/` and look at the code):

- Copy of original contacts manager app (works) - https://gist.run/?id=c73b047c8184c052b4c61c69febb33d8
- My changes in the app (do not work) - https://gist.run/?id=47c4f1c053adbdf46f6a33413dd12d3d

This is what I'm trying to do: in the original contacts app, there is this in `src/contact-list.html` which works fine:

```
<template>
  <div class="contact-list">
    <ul class="list-group">
      <li repeat.for="contact of contacts" class="list-group-item ${contact.id === $parent.selectedId ? 'active' : ''}">
        <a route-href="route: contacts; params.bind: {id:contact.id}" click.delegate="$parent.select(contact)">
          <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">${contact.firstName} ${contact.lastName}</h4>
          <p class="list-group-item-text">${contact.email}</p>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

Now, I'd like to replace the inner elements of the "looped" `li` - that is, the `a` with the `h4` and the `p` - with a new template.

So, I made `src/contact-list-item.html`:

```
<template>
  <a route-href="route: contacts; params.bind: {id:theContact.id}" click.delegate="$parent.$parent.select(theContact)">
    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">${theContact.firstName} ${theContact.lastName}</h4>
    <p class="list-group-item-text">${theContact.email}</p>
  </a>
</template>
```

... and `src/contact-list-item.js`:

```
import {bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class ContactListItem {
  @bindable theContact;
}
```

... and changed `src/contact-list.html` as:

```
<template>
  <require from="./contact-list-item"></require>

  <div class="contact-list">
    <ul class="list-group">
      <li repeat.for="contact of contacts" class="list-group-item ${contact.id === $parent.selectedId ? 'active' : ''}">
        <contact-list-item theContact.bind="contact"></contact-list-item>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

Basically, I've made a property in the `contact-list-item` class called `theContact`, and I'd like to bind it to the `contact` which is the looper variable in the `repeat.for="contact of contacts"` -- unfortunately, this doesn't work, as the data is not propagated (and so the contact names are empty). Also, the clicks on contact fiels do not propagate to show the details, even if I've changed `click.delegate="$parent.select(contact)"` to `click.delegate="$parent.$parent.select(theContact)"` in the new template.

What do I have to do, in order to have the data propagate form the `li` `repeate.for` loop, down to the new replacement template - and to have the app react on clicks on the new template?

Comment: Also possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36033773/what-is-the-correct-way-in-aurelia-to-bind-on-a-custom-element-using-repeat-for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Quick answer:**

In `contact-list.html`, change:

```
<contact-list-item theContact.bind="contact"></contact-list-item>
```

to:

```
<contact-list-item the-contact.bind="contact"></contact-list-item>
```

**Explanation:**

HTML is not case-sensitive, but the convention is to use only lower-case letters.  To respect that, Aurelia converts all camelCase variables to dash-case parameters and element names when interfacing with your HTML code.

**More Information:**

Dwayne Charrington wrote a good blog about this topic here:

http://ilikekillnerds.com/2016/06/dont-get-skewered-kebab-case-aurelia/

Comment: Oh, wow - I would *never* have expected this; many thanks @LStarky! In fact, I just replaced `theContact` with `thecontact` in `contact-list-item.html` and `contact-list-item.js`, and the code started working - *even* if `contact-list.html` **still** has `<contact-list-item theContact.bind="contact">` in camel case !! And even the click events work! Here is the changed working code: https://gist.run/?id=766cdd682b215a10ad9d7913ecd8d119

Comment: Glad you got it working.  The important thing is to remember how JavaScript, HTML and Aurelia handle case for variables, elements and properties.